# How can I put the result of a multi cell array formula in Excel into an array in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a relatively complex (I think) formula that results in a multi cell array formula. The user clicks a button on the interface sheet in Excel, and I want this to trigger some VBA code that puts the array result of the multi cell array formula into an array within a VBA sub.

The formula I need to use is the following:
`=FILTER(OFFSET(INDIRECT(Results!O22);0;-3);MOD(SEQUENCE(1;COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Results!O22)));5)=0)`

The value in Results!O22 is:
`="SumSheet_OffTrt"&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(rng_Data_start_ALL);MATCH(O23;INDIRECT("SumSheet_OffTrt"&"!"&ROW(rng_AddRows_ALL)&":"&ROW(rng_AddRows_ALL));0))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(rng_Data_start_ALL) + COUNTA(INDIRECT("SumSheet_OffTrt"&"!"&CHAR(64 + COLUMN(OFFSET(rng_Data_start_ALL;1;0)))&":"&CHAR(64 + COLUMN(OFFSET(rng_Data_start_ALL;1;0)))))-1;MATCH(P$6;INDIRECT("SumSheet_OffTrt"&"!"&ROW(rng_AddRows_ALL)&":"&ROW(rng_AddRows_ALL));0)-1)`

The result of the this crazy formula in Results!O22 is:
`SumSheet_OffTrt!$BY$14:$CR$68`, the range where some data are stored.

When the FILTER formula provided above is manually entered into Excel, the formula produces a functional multi cell array in the worksheet.

However, when I try to input the formula into Excel using VBA, it does not work.

Note, I am using a Swedish version of Excel, where the ";" is the separator. I have also attempted everything discussed below using a "," within the VBA code.

I have tried the following:

1. Using the Application.Evaluate method to set the value of an array equal to the formula result:

```
Dim strFrmla As String
Dim aryRsltData As Variant
strFrmla = =FILTER(OFFSET(INDIRECT(Results!O22);0;-3);MOD(SEQUENCE(1;COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Results!O22)));5)=0)
aryRsltData  = Application.Evaluate(strFrmla)
```

In this case, the aryRsltData has a value of Error 2015, or VALUE!.

2. Setting the value, formula, or formulaarray of a Range equal to a string variable of the formula, with the intention of setting the array equal to the resulting range value:

```
Dim strFrmla As String
strFrmla = =FILTER(OFFSET(INDIRECT(Results!O22);0;-3);MOD(SEQUENCE(1;COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Results!O22)));5)=0)

Sheet2.Range("A1").FormulaArray = strFrmla
```

The last line of code above triggers the following error: "Application-defined or object-defined error". Same error if I use `.Value` or `.Formula`.

3. I tried preventing Excel from responding to the value input, then I use VBA to place the formula, and then return Application defaults:

```
Dim strFrmla As String

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

strFrmla = =FILTER(OFFSET(INDIRECT(Results!O22);0;-3);MOD(SEQUENCE(1;COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Results!O22)));5)=0)

Sheet2.Range("A1").FormulaArray = strFrmla

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculate
```

The generated the same error as attempt #2.

4. I tried pasting the formula as text to the range, then clearing formats, and then calculating.

```
Dim strTargFrmla As String
strFrmla = =FILTER(OFFSET(INDIRECT(Results!O22);0;-3);MOD(SEQUENCE(1;COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Results!O22)));5)=0)

Sheet2.Range("A1").FormulaArray = "'" & strFrmla
Sheet2.Range("A1").ClearFormats
Application.Calculate
```

This gets the formula into the cell, even unformatted, but the user still needs to click the cell and press enter for the multi cell array to populate.

There was one similar discussion, and I have tried the suggestions where they seemed close to what I was doing:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50030749/insert-array-formula-in-excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com)
I have reviewed several other threads and cannot seem to find a solution.

Ultimately, what I am trying to do is simply get the resulting multi cell array into an array within VBA, so that I can proceed with adding a specific feature to the workbook.

Many thanks for any support anyone can provide. I am sure there are other ways I can reach my goal, so if nothing comes up here, I'll try again from the ground up.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the formula without `INDIRECT`? Something like `strFrmla = "=FILTER(OFFSET(" & [Results!O22] & ";0;-3);MOD(SEQUENCE(1;COLUMNS(" & [Results!O22] & "));5)=0)"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I still get the "Application-defined or object-defined error". Triggered by `Sheet2.Range("A1").Formula = strFrmla`

Comment: I thought you wanted to just `Evaluate(strFrmla)`. Try `Sheet2.Range("A1").FormulaArray = strFrmla`. Also run `Debug.Print strFrmla`. Copy and paste the ouput manually in the excel cell directly and see what happens. This should give you more insight. Could you also share the `Debug.Print` output with us.

Comment: SO is a US website and it is understood that the questions and the answers use the comma as the list separator. Also, VBA 'uses this setting', no matter which version of Excel, i.e. you have to convert your `strFrmla` (you can safely use `strFormula` or just `Formula`) to use commas instead of semicolons e.g. `strFrmla = "=FILTER(OFFSET(INDIRECT(Results!O22),0,-3),MOD(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(INDIRECT(Results!O22))),5)=0)"`. If you want to stick with the semicolons (not recommended), you have to use the 'local versions' e.g. `.FormulaLocal` although there is no local version of `.FormulaArray`.

Comment: "When the FILTER formula provided above is manually entered into Excel, the formula produces a functional multi cell array in the worksheet."  


So if this is true, have you tried  to record the macro and  execute it? Can you show us the recorded macro?

Comment: Very good idea to share to record a macro. That solved it. I recorded the macro when taking the step manually, and the resulting code used R1C1 reference style, and it also used commas (not semicolons). The following worked: `Sheet2.Range("A1").Formula2R1C1 = strTargFrmla`, where strTargFrmla is `=FILTER(OFFSET(INDIRECT('Results'!R22C15),0,-3),MOD(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(INDIRECT('Results'!R22C15))),5)=0)`

Comment: I'm not sure if it was the comma/semicolon issue or what else. @Super_Symmetry I tried using debug.print, but I'm admittedly a self taught programmer and when I added "Debug.Print" to the line that was failing, the only output in the immediate window was "False". If you're super curious, I have saved the original failing code, so feel free to let me know what I can do to get you the Debug.Print file if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

With the support of those commenting on the original post, a solution was found. Using the R1C1 reference style by setting strFrmla equal to `=FILTER(OFFSET(INDIRECT('Results'!R22C15),0,-3),MOD(SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(INDIRECT('Results'!R22C15))),5)=0)`, and then running the following solved the issue:
`Sheet2.Range("A1").Formula2R1C1 = strFrmla`

For some reason, using the R1C1 reference style worked. This was identified by using the record macro feature, and pasting the functional multi cell array formula manually as suggested in the comments.

Thanks all for the support, and feel free to comment if you understand why this is the case.